# Product field not filled in Shopware 6.5

Tags: vue.js, shopware, shopware6, twig.js

I added a own field by extending the product model. I also extended the templates, so the field is shown in the product edit detail view. If I enter some value into the field and save, it gets saved to the database.

The problem is, it wont show the data when I reload the page. The input field is always empty again.

```html
<sw-number-field label="Import ID" 
                         numberType="int" 
                         v-model="product.importId">
</sw-number-field>
```

I can change the value by doing this:

```js
Shopware.Component.override('sw-product-settings-form', {
    template,

    data: function () {
        return {
            product: {
                importId: "111111"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I configure it, that it fetches the actual value from the database?

Comment: Are you sure that the importId is saved to the database? This isn't a default field, as far as I know.

Comment: @Ezycod You are right, it is not a default field, I added it. But it does get saved to the db.

Comment: Is there any mapping or something behind the saving ? Or did you alter the product table and overwrite the product definition and entity?